# Using bg and fg with a given PID

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jobs

I am using Ubuntu.

If I am given a job’s PID, how can I bring the paused job to the background/foreground and running state?

I know `bg/fg` but they require `job id` not `PID`.

Also, I pause jobs with

```
kill -STOP <PID>
```

and I know that I can resume it with

```
kill -CONT <PID>
```

but I do not know how I can use bg and fg commands with this PID.

Edit: I want to make this clear:

Scenario: I have a paused job that I know its PID. How can I bring it back and make it work background?

Comment: BTW: It is a very good question! Another place to ask UNIX questions is unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: *bring it back and make it work background?* What does this even mean?

Comment: lets say I stopped a job with kill -STOP, if I want it to run again but on background, what should I do?

Answer (score 17):

You cannot use fg and bg with a pid. They are shell builtin-s which require a `jobspec`, not a pid.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. That is what both `bash` and `sh` documentation state, so it will not take the PID. Period.

Comment: Then is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You have two options: send SIGSTOP and SIGCONT to the process (kill), or use a jobspec with fg and bg. You can see running job ids and pids with `jobs -l`.

Comment: I don't think sending the SIGCONT works: I tried sending the CONT signal, but it did not restore my terminal output

Answer (score 3):

you can use `top` or `ps` command to see all of your `PID` and also you can use `pidof` command to gain `PID`

for example I wanna check the `PID` of `bash` command so I will write :

```
pidof bash
```

or with `ps` command you can write

```
ps -C bash
```

or with `ps` and `grep` you can write :

```
ps aux | grep bash
```

or just write `top` and check what ever you need.

for sending a command to `bg` or `background` you have to add `&` at the end of your command for example I wanna send `xeyes` to `bg` so I will write :

```
xeyes &
```

if you wanna bring it to `foreground` or `fg` you will write :

```
fg xeyes
```

you can also see all of your jobs with `jobs -l` command.

for example I want to run `xeyes` command so I will write :

```
xeyes
```

please attention to eyes when you moving your mouse, now if I want send it to `bg` I can use `CTRL+Z` on my keyboard.
if you want to check it you can write `jobs`
you will see `xeyes` is stopped !

left of each process is a number like this :

```
[1]-  6331 Running                 xeyes &
[2]+  Stopped                 xeyes
```

for example for me is 2 you can start your PID again like this :

```
bg %2
```

or you can find `PID` with `-l` in `jobs` to see `PIDs` too

```
[1]-  6331 Running                 xeyes &
[2]+  6332 Stopped                 xeyes
```

instead of `bg %2` I can write `bg 6332` to change state to Running !

and also you see `+` or `-` in this case, if the `+` sign was next to that process is stoped you can just write bg without any this like this :

```
bg # attention to +
```

if you want to bring your command to `fg` is exactly like `bg`, which means you can use one of that ways that I already mentioned !

I think about your question, it means the process has received a `STOP` signal, and won't do anything much until it receives a `CONT` signal, not even terminate.

Actually the most common source of `STOP` signals is the user hitting `CTRL+Z` while the process is in the `foreground`, and the common way to send a `CONT` afterwards is typing `fg` or `bg` which continue the process in the `foreground` and `background` respectively, another way to send `STOP` to a process is `kill -STOP PID`. Similarly, `CONT` can be sent to a process with kill `-CONT PID`.
Since you sent `TERM` signals to the processes, I assume you want them to terminate. For that to happen, the processes must receive `CONT` signals. You can send those by typing `kill -CONT 6331 6332` in a terminal window. please aware that these `PIDs` is belong to me and you have to change it to yours !

Comment: Those are not all portable examples. I just tried the first two on macOS Catalina and they did not work!  They do work on Debian Linux though.

Comment: thnx for your reply macOS is unix and his or her question is about linux Ubuntu!

Comment: Fair enough. Just pointing out the non-bash specific items. Wasn't aware of pidof, so wanted to try it.

Comment: So, in this case 6331 is the pid of process? I am not sure fg 6331 works

Comment: I already have PID of a process, what I need is to make a paused job come back to work in background

Comment: I updated the scenario of my question, you have a good point but the thing I am looking for is quite different

Comment: @HARUNSASMAZ or better than all that, use `pgrep`. But shells do not look up their children by PID: since it's the shell who exec'ed them, it just saves the arguments it had passed to `execve`.

Comment: This answer contains other innacuracies; for instance, Ctrl-Z (`VSUSP`) sends a `TSTP`, not a `STOP` signal, and it sends it the the whole foreground _process group_ (job), not just to a single process.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you find a way from now but in case and for other here is a workaround to get job's id from pid (and then use fg, bg command):

```
myJobId=$(jobs -l | grep $myPID | cut -c2)
```

$myPID contain the pid of the process

`jobs -l` gives the list of all jobs with their pid.
Then `grep $myPID` gives the corresponding line from that list.
Then `cut -c2` gives the second character of that line which is the id of the job.
this last command should be replace by a regex or something like that to get any digit between the first [] of the string (but it work fine for me as i have only 2 bg process)

Comment: Surround the pid with spaces and quotes so not to match another process then this solution is fine: `myJobId=$(jobs -l | grep " $myPID " | cut -c2)`