# How to have two running processes in Linux terminal? (Linux command)

Tags: linux, command-line, graphql, react-apollo

I was following React + Apollo tutorial, but had to stop at the point to ask me to run the server and app simultaneously. I tried to run the app first by 'yarn start' in the current directory and move to 'server' directory to run the server by 'yarn dev' after terminating the app, 'ctrl + c', which isn't running two things at the same time.

**What I Did**

in apollo directory

> yarn start

> ctrl + c

> cd server

in server directory

> yarn dev

**How can I run the server(in server directory) and app(in apollo directory) at the same time? Thanks!**

Comment: Many options (background jobs, screen, tmux, …) come to mind, but why not simply open a second terminal and run your second command there?

Comment: @knittl Thank you. I didn't know that I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way in my opinion is:

```
program1 &
program2 &
```

This will run both program in the background.
If using this as a part of a script, you can use `wait` as well.

You might find other commands useful:

```
jobs # prints all jobs running in the background
fg [job_id] - foreground, brings the program to the front.
bg [job_id] - background, sends a program to the background.
CTRL+Z - suspends a job running in the front. You'll be able to see it when running jobs.
```

There are a few other options. To deeply understand this you need to be familiar with how processes work as a part of the OS.

See [How do you run multiple programs in parallel from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script), [Using bg and fg with a given PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476078/using-bg-and-fg-with-a-given-pid)

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal window there should be a button in the top right corner, this will open a new tab. You should be able to run both in separate tabs, I typically start the server first.
Mine looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuKqN.png)